# Creating Javascript functions in Objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c

How could I implement Javascript in Objective-C so that I can basically add native functions to javascript?

For example:
evaluating the javascript code "drawrectangle();"
would call some objective-C method to draw a rectangle on the screen

Comment: You are aware that with the html5 canvas, you can draw rectangles in the browser window? http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-rectangles/  Maybe you could give a better example scenario for why you think you need to extend Javascript with native methods.

Comment: I think there might be a fundamental misunderstanding here.  Is this Javascript that is running in a browser?

Comment: People are far more inclined to buy an app than to view a web page.  And how the canvas flashes grey for a second when you tap on bugs me

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSCocoa](http://inexdo.com/JSCocoa) or [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey).